# asp vb ReportViewer page break by column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

I have a simple report that display location and its data. I want to make report that column is location and rows are its data. One page display only one location.

Here is example of data and current ouput:
Location A, B, C.
Data: A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3.

Currently output (Using tablix, group by column location)

```
A   B   C
A1  B1  C1
A2  B2  C2
A3  B3  C3
```

Expected output

```
Page1: 
A
A1
A2
A3
Page 2
B
B1
B2
B3
Page 3
C
C1
C2
C3
```

I'm already setting page break between each instance of a group for column group but it seem to not work. (When group by row, its work but

(I'm using visual studio 2012, ReportViewerWebControl is version 11.0.0.0. I want to page break by column because actually I have many columns and want to page break after each 5 columns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my self using idea of this site 
http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/

1. Firt add 2 columns for table adapter (PageNum and ColumnNum)
2. Group by PageNum, duplicate table and then filter by ColumnNum.